# How do get the ID field in App Engine Datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Say I have a blog on Google AppEngine and wants to print out the id of each post through jinja2.

```
blog = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Blog')

self.render('blog.html', blog = blog)
```

and in the template:

```
{{% for b in blog %}}
{{b.id}}
{{% endfor %}}
```

Now I havent added an 'id' field to my DB model, I just want to access the build in datastore ID field. How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the db key class. When you have an entity you can do:

```
entity.key().id_or_name()
```

or in NDB:

```
entity.key.id()
```

Comment: So the answer is (in jinjia2, as requested by the OP): `{{b.key.id_or_name}}`